# Loop two array of same size display on a table Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to loop two array of same size display on the same row in a table

```
<g:each in="${productList}"  var="p"> 
    <td>${p}</td>
</g:each>
<g:each in="${cartList}" status="i" var="c">                
    <td>${fieldValue(bean: c, field: "quantity")}</td>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another way is to use the status:

```
<g:each in="${cartList}" status="i" var="c">                
   <td>${productList[i]}</td>
   <td>${fieldValue(bean: c, field: "quantity")}</td>
</g:each>
```

...but the transpose() method seems to me cleaner :-)

Comment: Your way doesn't introduce a new List object though which for massive carts could be a bonus :-)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will work (or if I completely understand your question), but you could try:

```
<g:each var="prodcart" in="${[productList,cartList].transpose()}">
  <td>${prodcart[0]}</td>
  <td>${fieldValue( bean:prodcart[1], field:'quantity')}</td>
</g:each>
```

The [`transpose()` method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#transpose%28%29) does the following:

```
products = [ 'hammer', 'chisel', 'crowbar' ]
quantity = [ 1,        2,        5         ]

println( [products,quantity].transpose() )
```

would print:

```
[[hammer, 1], [chisel, 2], [crowbar, 5]]
```